# button that creates object

Tags: javascript, object

1. Could someone tell me how could I create a new object with a function?
2. How could I change the name of the object every time that the function works?
   Example: Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4...
3. Create an array with all of those new objects

```js
function CreateObject() {
// Create an object
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateObject()"></button>
```

```js
// The result should be:
var allObjects = [Object1,Object2,Object3];
let Object1 = {
name: "hello"
}
let Object2 = {
name: "hello"
}
let Object3 = {
name: "hello"
}
```

Comment: `var object = {}` ?

Comment: can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: Okay. I will write examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the button is clicked, count the amount of objects already in the main objext and use a template literal to add the next one:

```js
let objs = {}
function CreateObject() {
  let idx = Object.keys(objs).length + 1
  objs[`Object${idx}`] = {name: 'hello'}
  console.log(objs)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateObject()">Add Object</button>
```

Comment: A small addition for OP. With functions that start with an uppercased letter, like `CreateObject` it's assumed that it is an [object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#displaying_the_constructor_of_an_object) and should be used in combination with the `new` keyword. For example: `const object = new CreateObject()`. Function that do not act as  object constructors should start with a lowercased letter. This pattern is used throughout JavaScript and will tell you by reading the function *how* you should use it.